# C++: Best text accumulator

Tags: performance, file, boost, boost-asio, streambuf

Text gets accumulates piecemeal before being sent to client.

Now we use own class that allocates memory for each piece as char massive. (Anyway, works like `char[][]` + `std::list<char*>`).

Then we build the whole string, convert it into std::sting and then create `boost::asio::streambuf` using it. That's slow enough, I assume. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I know, in many cases simple `FILE` type from `stdio.h` is used. How does it works? Allocates memory at every write into it. So, is it faster and is there any way to read into `boost::asio::streambuf` from `FILE`?

**ADD**: Hm. I've forgot one big thing :). The compilation of dlls and main application is made under few compilers, so it should have no stl stuff inside it ... Because it usually cause a lot of problems, while executing dlls.

Comment: Hah, even a single comment :)

Comment: My question seems to be bad formulated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea how efficient it is, but I usually use a ostringstream for that sort of thing

Comment: Same here, it does the job and is built in (no extra libraries required) just do #include <sstream>.

Comment: I don't like non-stdio.h I\O operations, so that's what I meant saying FILE type from stdio.h. It must be faster. (Don't like streams' I\O, anyway.)

Comment: Why do you assume it must be faster? The C++ library is built on the same base functions and written by some very smart people that can probably optimize things better than you or I

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html

Comment: Great thing. I'll just have to check out on the content of stl inside it. And compare speed of rope, FILE type and our stuff (I assume rope, as a complicated project of big group of programmers should work faster). Thanks.

Comment: hah ) I was getting ready to check out of content of stl in this thing :)). Never knew about such stl container.